# How to use distinct in a grouped query?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I created this view from couple tables. Each employee able to work all stores. Each invoice could have one product or more than one. What I want to show,
Store, Employee, Individual product total sales, Total Transaction (which means a total invoice number), Total of Invoices.
Here is an example table:

```
CREATE TABLE PerformanceView
([Store] varchar(6), [Employee] varchar(5), [Product] varchar(8), [ProductPrice] int,[InvoiceNo] int, [InvoiceTotal] int);

 INSERT INTO PerformanceView
([Store], [Employee], [Product], [ProductPrice], [InvoiceNo], [InvoiceTotal])
VALUES
('Store1', 'Empl1', 'Product1', 577.2, 42152, 676.2),
('Store1', 'Empl1', 'Product1', 99, 42152, 676.2),
('Store1', 'Empl1', 'Product2', 20, 41969, 20),
('Store1', 'Empl1', 'Product2', 25, 41649, 25),
('Store1', 'Empl2', 'Product2', 300, 43112, 300),
('Store1', 'Empl2', 'Product2', 450, 42440, 450),
('Store1', 'Empl2', 'Product3', 226, 41666, 2040.14),
('Store1', 'Empl2', 'Product3', 282.17, 42232, 1678.5),
('Store1', 'Empl2', 'Product3', 934.67, 41666, 2040.14),
('Store1', 'Empl2', 'Product3', 1264.56, 42232, 1678.5),
('Store1', 'Empl2', 'Product4', 49.81, 41666, 2040.14),
('Store1', 'Empl2', 'Product4', 683.32, 41666, 2040.14),
('Store1', 'Empl2', 'Product4', 0, 42232, 1678.5),
('Store1', 'Empl2', 'Product4', 81.92, 42232, 1678.5),
('Store1', 'Empl2', 'Product4', 146.34, 41666, 2040.14),
('Store1', 'Empl2', 'Product4', 49.85, 42232, 1678.5),
('Store1', 'Empl2', 'Product5', 30, 43110, 30),
('Store1', 'Empl3', 'Product1', 172.5, 42875, 172.5),
('Store3', 'Empl4', 'Product2', 51, 42801, 51),
('Store3', 'Empl4', 'Product2', 51, 42488, 51),
('Store3', 'Empl4', 'Product2', 80.002, 42463, 80.002),
('Store3', 'Empl4', 'Product2', 22, 42559, 22),
('Store3', 'Empl4', 'Product2', 20, 42963, 20),
('Store3', 'Empl4', 'Product2', 35, 42436, 35),
('Store3', 'Empl4', 'Product2', 107, 43014, 107),
('Store3', 'Empl4', 'Product2', 59, 42615, 59),
('Store3', 'Empl4', 'Product2', 110, 42025, 110),
('Store3', 'Empl4', 'Product2', 89, 42137, 148),
('Store3', 'Empl4', 'Product2', 50, 42565, 100),
('Store3', 'Empl4', 'Product2', 59, 42137, 148),
('Store3', 'Empl4', 'Product5', 25, 42565, 100),
('Store3', 'Empl4', 'Product5', 25, 42565, 100),
('Store3', 'Empl5', 'Product2', 22, 42295, 44),
('Store3', 'Empl5', 'Product2', 22, 42295, 44),
('Store3', 'Empl5', 'Product2', 439, 41723, 439),
('Store3', 'Empl5', 'Product2', 197, 42267, 197),
('Store3', 'Empl5', 'Product2', 150, 41780, 150),
('Store3', 'Empl5', 'Product2', 539, 42280, 539),
('Store3', 'Empl5', 'Product2', 63, 41689, 63),
('Store3', 'Empl5', 'Product2', 269, 42274, 269),
('Store3', 'Empl5', 'Product2', 134, 41731, 134),
('Store2', 'Empl3', 'Product1', 0, 43076, 0),
('Store2', 'Empl3', 'Product1', 149.49, 42557, 666.73),
('Store2', 'Empl3', 'Product1', 0, 43076, 0),
('Store2', 'Empl3', 'Product1', 0, 42917, 0),
('Store2', 'Empl3', 'Product1', 61.01, 42557, 666.73),
('Store2', 'Empl3', 'Product1', 389.4, 42557, 666.73),
('Store2', 'Empl3', 'Product1', 66.84, 42557, 666.73),
('Store2', 'Empl3', 'Product1', 0, 43076, 0),
('Store2', 'Empl3', 'Product1', 15.42, 41650, 15.42),
('Store2', 'Empl3', 'Product1', 0, 43088, 0),
('Store2', 'Empl3', 'Product1', 0, 42920, 0),
('Store2', 'Empl3', 'Product6', 0, 43076, 0);
```

I have tried this code;

```
select 
STORE,
EMPLOYEE,
PRODUCT,
SUM(ProductPrice) as ProductTotal ,
SUM(InvoiceTotal) as InvoiceTotal,
Count(Distinct InvoiceNo) as Transactions
from 
PerformanceView 
GROUP BY STORE,EMPLOYEE,PRODUCT
```

But the Invoice Total is wrong Because of it sums same invoices have.
You can check it in here http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/e419f/6
I have tried over clause but it did not give the same view.

Comment: If it has same invoiceNo, what would you want to include in the total? the minimum or the max?

Comment: Is the InvoiceTotal stored with each row the Total for the entire invoice or is it the total for just that Product from the Invoice?  For example, Invoice 42232 shows up several times and has the same InvoiceTotal, but no indication how much product was sold for that line.  You need to have something you can use to know how much of that InvoiceTotal belongs to that product, then you can sum it up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is that your view holds single product sales (one line per piece of product sold), but you also have redundantly the invoice invoice amount with it. When grouping by store, employee and product, you count the invoice amount many-fold. So you must first group by store, employee, product *and invoiceno*, and only then get to the final group:

```
select 
  store,
  employee,
  product,
  sum(producttotal) as producttotal,
  sum(invoicetotal) as invoicetotal,
  count(*) as transactions
from
(
  select 
    store,
    employee,
    product,
    sum(productprice) as producttotal,
    min(invoicetotal) as invoicetotal
  from performanceview 
  group by store, employee, product, invoiceno
) as pre_aggregate
group by store, employee, product;
```

Here is your SQL fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/e419f/32.

Answer (score 0):

From looking at the input data, I notice duplicate rows such as:

```
('Store3', 'Empl4', 'Product5', 25, 42565, 100),
('Store3', 'Empl4', 'Product5', 25, 42565, 100),
('Store3', 'Empl5', 'Product2', 22, 42295, 44),
('Store3', 'Empl5', 'Product2', 22, 42295, 44),
```

So in order to sanitize this use an inline view of this form:

```
select [Store], [Employee], [Product], [ProductPrice], [InvoiceNo], [InvoiceTotal]
from PerformanceView 
group by [Store], [Employee], [Product], [ProductPrice], [InvoiceNo], [InvoiceTotal]
```

Like so:

```
select 
    pv.STORE,
    pv.EMPLOYEE,
    pv.PRODUCT,
    SUM(pv.ProductPrice) as ProductTotal ,
    SUM(pv.InvoiceTotal) as InvoiceTotal,
    Count(Distinct pv.InvoiceNo) as Transactions
from 
(
    select [Store], [Employee], [Product], [ProductPrice], [InvoiceNo], [InvoiceTotal]
    from PerformanceView 
    group by [Store], [Employee], [Product], [ProductPrice], [InvoiceNo], [InvoiceTotal]

) pv
GROUP BY pv.STORE, pv.EMPLOYEE, pv.PRODUCT
```